# serial port call

Tags: serial-port

I want to open a serial port cash drawer connected to the client pc.  I will have a record button on an asp page and when I click on it the drawer will open

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to communicate with the serial port. Web browsers typically cannot do this, so you probably want to call a program on the system.

One way to do this would be with Java Server Pages - you can call a Java application using JNI to communicate with the serial port. Look online for serial communication libraries using your favorite language.

Comment: Shame there's no "ser:" URI scheme. :-)

Comment: I'm sure you could make one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, a serial port is just a file. The simplest way to use it is just opening it r/w and fire away.